# How to loop through divs with no knowledge of what the user viewed and what they WANT to view

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a set of DIVs

One DIV is initially set without the .hidden attribute all others have it.

I have a set of HREF's the call a DIV that will make it SHOW.

I have a css for "HIDDEN display: none;" and "SHOW display: block;"

I want to be able to LOOP through all the divs, remove the .hidden attribute for the selected div and place the .hidden attribute for the OLD div...

Simple right? My knowledge of JQ is limited and bumping along the road... like now.

Here's the code:

```
<section id='content'>
  <div id='stuff1' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff2' class='somestuff'>
      <p>Hello World 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff3' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff4' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 4</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff5' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 5</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's the NAV:

```
<div id='nav'>
   <a href='#' onclick='changePage(this.id)' id='stuff1'>Click for Content 1</a>
   <a href='#' onclick='changePage(this.id)' id='stuff2'>Click for Content 2</a>
   <a href='#' onclick='changePage(this.id)' id='stuff3'>Click for Content 3</a>
   <a href='#' onclick='changePage(this.id)' id='stuff4'>Click for Content 4</a>
   <a href='#' onclick='changePage(this.id)' id='stuff5'>Click for Content 5</a>    
</div>
```

And finally what I believe is the function:

```
<script>

        function changePage(currPage)
        {

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#' + currPage + 'Page .contentBody').each(function(i, j) {
                    console.log(i); //the i
                    console.log(j); //the div

                    $('#' + currPage + 'Page' + "Page").removeClass('hiddenstuff');
                    $('#' + currPage + 'Page' + "Page").addClass('hiddenstuff');

                });
            });

        }       


</script>
```

Yeah, I know this function is all over the place, but essentially, how do I know what the user will click and when they do, which one did they just leave and which one are they going to??? Hmmmmm?

thanks

Comment: Easy. the one they clicked is the one that is targeted by the click event, and the previous one is the one that doesn't have the .hidden class. Remove the id's from your anchor tags, they don't belong there.

Comment: You should never have a duplicated `id` value within the same document.  They must always be unique.

Comment: his code makes me believe they are unique, note the addition of "Page" to the id when selecting the content divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this kind of work is done by using the href of the anchor tag so that it can gracefully degrade in a non-javascript environment.

Secondly, rather than passing the id of the anchor tag, why not pass the href since it's now in the href? Or, while we're at it, just pass `this` completely. Also, you'll want to return the response from changePage so that we can prevent a page jump.

```
<a href='#stuff1' onclick='return changePage(this)'>Click for Content 1</a>
<a href='#stuff2' onclick='return changePage(this)'>Click for Content 2</a>
<a href='#stuff3' onclick='return changePage(this)'>Click for Content 3</a>
```

Now, we can take "Page" off of the content div id's.

```
<section id='content'>
  <div id='stuff1' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff2' class='somestuff'>
      <p>Hello World 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff3' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff4' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 4</p>
  </div>
  <div id='stuff5' class='somestuff hidden'>
      <p>Hello World 5</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

With all that in place, this is how the javascript would look:

```
function changePage(el) {
    var target = $(el).attr("href"); // using jQuery to avoid an IE inconsistency
    $(target).show().siblings().hide();
    // prevent page jump
    return false;
}
```

Simple right? well, it can be simpler.

```
<a href='#stuff1' class="changepage">Click for Content 1</a>
<a href='#stuff2' class="changepage">Click for Content 2</a>
<a href='#stuff3' class="changepage">Click for Content 3</a>
```

and the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".changepage").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr("href"); // using jQuery to avoid an IE inconsistency
        $(target).show().siblings().hide();
        // prevent page jump
        return false;
    });
});
```

To make this degrade as mentioned in the beginning, add a no-script tag that includes an inline style that shows the .hidden divs.

Answer (score 0):

first of all **you don't need document.ready inside a function**.. secondly **id should always be unique**.. multiple elements with same id is invalid.

try this

change your `<a>` id to `data-id` (using HTML5 data attributes). this should make all the  ids unique.

```
 <a href='#' onclick='changePage(this)' data-id='stuff1'>Click for Content 1</a>
```

and javascript (jquery)

```
function changePage(currObj)
{
   $('.somestuff').addClass('hidden'); 
   $('#' + $(currObj).data('id')).removeClass('hidden');

}
```

considering `somestuff` class is present in all the divs. if not add common class to all the div and use class selector..